# Angular 5 routing with nested components

Tags: nested, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router, nested-views

OK So for sake of simplicity lets say I have 3 components: a parent component and two other components (child A and child B).

I want parent component to **have an url prefix of '/parent' and contain one of the two other components**, component A by default, else B, who have their own url prefixes of **'childA' and 'childB'** respectively. Also I do not want parent component to to be viewable by itself, it must have either childA or childB viewable and **if '/parent' is called it will automatically re-route to '/parent/childA'.**

So far this is what I have in my router and it is not working I am getting an invalid path error on the console when I route to '/parent' and when I route to '/parent/child[AorB]' my browser lags forever and never routes:

```
{
  path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent,
  children : [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'childA' 
    },
    {
      path: 'childA',
          component: ChildAComponent
    }, {
      path: 'childB',
      component: childBComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

parent's template is just a router-outlet like so:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add **pathMatch: 'full'** like so:

```
{
  path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent,
  children : [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'childA',
      pathMatch: 'full' //<--------- Need this here
    },
    {
      path: 'childA',
          component: ChildAComponent
    }, {
      path: 'childB',
      component: childBComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 2 **router-outlet** defined in your html, so angular would know which is the parent and which is the child..

How is the code for your links?
For the children, user the './', like so:

```
[routerLink]="['./childA']"
```

For parent, you can go directly...

```
[routerLink]="['parent']"
```